# How can I make it so only the logged in user view his own grade?

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio, stored-procedures, mysql-workbench

[This is the student info table where the student info comes from](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1XTjy.png)    //This is the login code for the user and it get the user log in info from the studentinfo table.

```
private void btnlogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        i = 0;
        con.Open();
        MySqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();

        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "select * from stdinfotable WHERE Username='" + textuser.Text + "' and Password= '" + textpass.Text + "'";
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        MySqlDataAdapter dta = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        dta.Fill(dt);

        i = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows.Count.ToString());

        if(i==0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error");
        }
        else
        {
            this.Hide();
            StudentPage f = new StudentPage();
            f.Show();
            MySqlDataAdapter data = new MySqlDataAdapter("ViewAllGrades", con);
            data.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            DataTable dtTable = new DataTable();

            data.Fill(dtTable);
            dtTable.Select("Last_Name");

            f.stdGrade.DataSource = dtTable;
            f.stdGrade.Columns[0].Visible = false;
        }

        con.Close();
}
```

This is the `ViewlAllGrades` stored procedure where the grade info is returned from

```
 CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `ViewAllGrades`()
 BEGIN
    SELECT * 
  FROM  Grades;

  END
```

I am trying to make it so only the logged in user can view his own grade rather than viewing every user grade. So I am wondering should I try to do within the stored procedure or in Visual Studio and how would I achieve such thing? Also my primary keys which are ID are from both table are auto incremented so I cant not necessarily use those

Comment: This question does not have enough information, and the tags are incorrect, please update your question adding more details.
Do not store plain passwords in the database, never! Google about the topic, hash the passwords for example.
Moreover, you should try to organise your code better and give variables meaningful names.

Comment: @Manuel How? all the tags are correct it what I am using every single tag has to do with my code. Also, what others details can I add?

Comment: Tags like mysql and mysql-workbench are not really necessary here, but tag aside, the code you shared seems to be doing already what you say, in the else statement you already populate a table, is that code not producing the desired effects?

Comment: @Manuel no the code works but not the way I want it. When the user logs in with his credentials he should only view his own grade and not everyone else that where I need help. I just want the logged in user to be able to view his own info.

Comment: I see, you need to run a query filtering by the user ID.
Do not use a stored procedure to read data, use a select statement.
When you authenticate the user, you get back a list of rows, that in theory should only be one. Check the table stdinfotable , look for an ID and use that ID to filter the table grades

Comment: @Manuel how can I put this in code language I am still a beginner.

Comment: In order to be able to answer you need to add some more details, like the data structure.

Comment: @Norcino what do you mean by data structure? I am learning this by myself if you could help I would really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

Right now your stored procedure is selecting all of the grades. First thing to do would be to parameterize the query, accepting the user as the input, and using the WHERE clause to find only the grades for that student. Without seeing your tables, I cannot tell you exactly what this would look like, but as an example:  SELECT * FROM Grades WHERE StudentId = @StudentId;

The second thing you need to figure out is how to get the current user's student id and then pass it to the stored procedure. Again, without seeing your tables, I can hardly guess. It appears you already have the username of the current user. Are you able to run a query to find the studentId from the username? If so, then you first need to run that procedure with username as the parameter to get the studentId.

A third concern is with your first query. Since it has not been parameterized, it is susceptible to SQL injection attacks. This poses a MAJOR security risk. If someone maliciously enters a username or password, they can escape the SQL you intended to run and drop all of your tables.

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: I just put in the studentinfo table